# git filter-branch messed up my contribution graph (green squares on GitHub)

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch

After running "git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch .idea' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
", my contribution graph on my profile got messed up. The number of commits has doubled, but when I checked, the actual number of commits seems to be fewer than what is displayed. Is there any way to fix this issue?

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch .idea" --prune-empty -- --all
```

Comment: That's exactly what filter-branch does. It rewrites a completely new history. Don't use it unless you intend to forget the original history. Evidently the old commits are still reachable from some refs